Unable to identify syntax required to rename files in MacOS Terminal
This is a head scratcher.
I need to move these three oddly-named files from an external 2.5" SSD to my desktop. The file names were intended to have variables replaced by date info, however, clearly it didn't work. So I'm left with these filenames that MacOS seems to want to interpret rather than treat as a string. I wish it was as easy as tossing in single quotes or escaping chars, but so far, that hasn't worked.
Files: Test01-$(internal:date_y)-$(internal:date_m)-$(internal:date_d)-.mp4 Test01-$(internal:date_y)-$(internal:date_m)-$(internal:date_d)-0001.mp4 Test01-$(internal:date_y)-$(internal:date_m)-$(internal:date_d)-0002.mp4
I'm on MacOS. In the Finder, the files are not visible. But they are not hidden files.
In Terminal, however, when I navigate to "/Volumes/TestDrive", then run a quick "ls", I can see all three files no problem. Including permissions, size, owners, full filename, etc.
However, when I attempt to move the files to my desktop, and rename in the process (even if I don't rename), Terminal tells me that "No such file or folder can be found" or something very close to that.
I've tried using mv and cp commands to put the filename in single quotes so the filename is read literally. Yet, I'm still given feedback that the file cannot be transferred because it cannot be found or doesn't exist.
mv 'Test01-$(internal:date_y)-$(internal:date_m)-$(internal:date_d)-.mp4' ~/Desktop/Test01-01.mp4' 'cp 'Test01-$(internal:date_y)-$(internal:date_m)-$(internal:date_d)-.mp4' ~/Desktop/Test01-01.mp4
When I try to escape special characters instead of quotes, I am also told the file doesn't exist. But clearly it does when I list out the contents of the drive. And there's only 3x .mp4 files, two hiddne files .fseventsd and some spotlight file.
mv Test01-\$\(internal\:date_y\)-\$\(internal\:date_m\)-\$\(internal\:date_d\)-.mp4 ~/Desktop/Test01-01.mp4
I've tried copying by inode. No luck. I've tried pulling the videos into ffmpeg (CLI based media mgmt tool) to see if I can get some info on the files, and same thing, ffmpeg (or ffprobe) both will tell me the file doesn't exist...even though I can list the files and see that it does.
I hope I'm missing something obvious, but but it seems all the obvious approaches are not yet working for me.
So my question is, what do I need to do to make these files "exist" so that I can rename them and back them up? Happy to go down any rabbit hole.
Thanks in advance!

Make sure there are no special characters (like spaces) at the beginning or end of the file names.

Try using the shell's tab-completion feature. Type in mv Test then press the tab key and it should fill in a properly-escaped filename up to the first character where the names differ, then type the next character of one of the tilenames to tell it which one you want. tab again, etc until you've got the full filename.

@Philippe - Confirmed no special chars (or spaces).

@GordonDavisson - This was an excellent tip. I did confirm my escapes are correct using your method. The only additional escapes I added were before the colons because in some instances they were being converted to underscores. Unfortunately, it didn't resolve lead to resolution of the issue.

Welp, I fixed the problem. I suspect it was a filesystem corruption on the storage partition of the SSD. I think that's why I could see the files listed in Terminal, but could not see them via Finder.
Anyway, it turns out the issue was resolvable by repairing the disk drive using "First Aid" in Disk Utility from Recovery Mode. I don't know that the naming scheme had anything to do with the corruption.
To fix my problem, I rebooted my Mac into Recovery Mode (CMD + R at boot) to make sure there wasn't any processes running against the mounted SSD. Pulled up Terminal to run "diskutil info" on the drive. There was an error in the output from that command AND it listed the filenames as problematic.
I closed Terminal. Opened up Disk Utility (rather than accessing via terminal). I ran First Aid on the problem drive. Then rebooted into regular MacOS (not recovery mode). When I opened the external disk up again in the Finder, I could see the files, special characters and all. I successfully renamed the files using Finder and was able to move the files to their final destination.

What format is the volume in, and how were the files written to the disk? In particular, were they written by something other than macOS, something which doesn't fully understand macOS' volume formats? I ask because at least with HFS+ (aka "Mac OS Extended") there's some weird encoding stuff with colons and slashes that might've been done wrong. See "Colon (:) appears as forward slash (/) when creating file name" and "The Challenges of Integrating the Unix and Mac OS Environments".

@GordonDavisson, the drive's file system is exFAT. The files are written via a video recording device (Blackmagic Hyperdeck Studio 4k Pro). The recording is simply started and stopped by hand. The file creation was done so properly...as in no loss of power or pulling the drive too early. In case you're not familiar, it's a common, professional workflow in live events and broadcast. I wish I hadn't fixed the issue because I would love to resolve the colon conundrum. Based on your (good) reads,  I have a much healthier respect for the complexity and variation among filesystems. Thank you again!

Interesting. Microsoft's spec for exFAT forbids both colon and slash in filenames (along with a bunch of others). I just did a quick test, and macOS appears to support colon (and at least some of the others), but with a weird character encoding. My guess is that the Blackmagic deck also allows them, but with a different encoding, and that's what confused macOS.

That is interesting. The Blackmagic recorder lets you format to HFS+ also. However, I do exFAT for compatibility. Then the codec I record in is ProRes, which is Apple's codec. So seeing the discrepancies between lower level syntax and any layer above, I can see the potential for conflicts until isolating syntactical expectations. Or maybe some weird hybrid in this instance.

It is the colon that causes problem, try this :
mv 'Test01-$(internal'*'date_y)-$(internal'*'date_m)-$(internal'*'date_d)-.mp4' ~/Desktop/Test01-01.mp4


Thinking that wildcards the colon and tells it to explicitly whatever that asterisk represents right? I was getting some "no command found" issues depending on what I was running. I think the colon may have been a contributing factor, but didn't fully understand the implications of the syntax. That aside, I solved the issue without addressing the colon or special characters. Posting shortly. Thank you Philippe for the quick responses! Much appreciated.
